# Facebook Sharer on mobiles not working

Tags: facebook

I have a website http://coolfuzz.com

when I share any article through desktop, laptop it is working fine. But when I am trying to share it through mobile, I am getting an error.

> The page you requested cannot be displayed right now. It may be
>   temporarily unavailable, the link you have clicked on may be broken or
>   expired, or you may not have permissions to view this page.

My traffic is 90% mobile driven so I am losing a lot of visitors. I have tried installing different plugins but no benefit. I have gone through the code for one full day but no reason why it is giving me this error?

Please tell me how to solve this issue?

The page, if anyone want to try for the use case could be http://coolfuzz.com/what-if-ms-dhoni-would-be-an-it-project-manager/

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: How are you sharing? Just from the mobile app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered the same problem in which sharer works on desktop version but throws "temporarily unavailable" on mobile (m.facebook.com).

Then, I made the Facebook App live, and the problem is solved.

Go to your app at developers.facebook.com > Status & Review.

Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public? **Yes.**